# Ajax and PDO prepared requests

Tags: php, ajax, pdo

In the process of creating an Ajax chat, I need to call every X time units a PHP script which makes a simple request to check if there are new messages in the database.

Since only one variable changes in the checking process, I thought I could use PDO prepared requests - which I have heard of only recently.

However, I quickly faced a problem; in order to keep my prepared request for each Ajax call, I needed to store my PDO object in a session... and I soon discovered PDO couldn't be serialized.

I then discovered persistent connections - but I am not really aware of how to use them.

First off, is that really needed? Is it worth using prepared requests?
If prepared requests are needed, how can I efficiently store a prepared request to use it in every of my Ajax calls?

Thanks!

Comment: Make the next step and implement a Push notification-like system!

Comment: you use arrays or json type of arrays carry them over insert into database.

Comment: STTLCU: Uh? / Erdem Ece: What do you mean? Are prepared requests somewhat storable in the DB?

Comment: I doubt you'll be happy with ajax based chat..look at [websocket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) or [rtmp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_Time_Messaging_Protocol)

Comment: I don't know about any of these, but I'll have a look. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't use prepared statement between calls.
No, it is not worth nor necessary in order to run the same query across different requests.

However, you **ought** to use prepared statements in order **to make your queries properly formatted**.

So, just create another PDO object every time your page called, and use prepared statement to run a query.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I had heard prepared requests were better in the case of repeated operations; why do you say they are not necessary in that case?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, and sorry to bother again, but what's the point of prepared statements if I re-prepare them every ajax call? And what do mean by "properly formatted"? Thanks again!

Comment: The point in having query properly formatted. Properly formatted means having correct syntax.

Comment: There are 2 ways to create a query dynamically: you can just add some value directly into query, or prepare a query using a placeholder in place of the actual value. Only the latter one can make sure that added value would not spoil the query, either erroneous or malicious way. That's the only real purpose for the prepared statements.